# Linear operator that transforms uniform convergence to pointwise convergence is continuous

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

> Let $H$ be the space of continuous real functions over $[0,1]$ with the supremum norm
>
> Let $A:H\to H$ be a linear operator such that if $f_n\to f$ (in the sense of uniform convergence) then $A(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $A(f)$
>
> Prove that $A$ is continous.

Since $A$ is linear, it suffices to prove that $A$ is continuous at $0$. That is to say, given a sequence $f_n\in H$ such that $||f_n||_\infty\to 0$, one must prove that $A(f_n)$ converges uniformly to the $0$ function (it is already known that $A(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$).

My thoughts so far: for each $n$, $A(f_n)$ is a continous, hence uniformly continuous function. So for each $n$, we can control locally how $A(f_n)$ behaves.

Furthermore, $A(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $0$. Therefore, we can relate the $A(f_i)$ on a countable subset of $[0,1]$ (rationals).

Nevertheless, I can't find a way to control uniformly the $A(f_i)$ (I know only how each $A(f_n)$ behaves individually, and that the sequences $(A(f_n)(r_i))_n$ go to $0$ where the $r_i$ are rationals.)

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Use the closed graph theorem.

Comment: @Etienne this problem is among the first in my functional analysis course, and this theorem does not seem to be in the syllabus.

Comment: OK; so I don't have an answer right now...

Comment: It seems to me that some kinds of Baire category theorem is inevitable. Not sure though.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM What theorems do you have at your disposal?

Comment: @Etienne any undergraduate real-analysis/topology theorem (including Baire theorem)

Comment: Do you know that polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$ (Stone-Weierstrass)?

Comment: @SamM yes, I know this.

Comment: Maybe try some polynomial approximations, since you can then use some integral estimates in the image.

Comment: @Etienne Now that I have closed graph theorem at my disposal, the exercise has become a mere triviality :P

Comment: The closed graph theorem is a nice theorem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us prove this using "only" the Baire category theorem.

By assumption, for every fixed $x\in [0,1]$, the linear functional $f\mapsto Af(x)$ is continuous. It follows that for any $N\in\mathbb N$, the set 
$$F_N:=\{ f\in H;\; \Vert Af\Vert_\infty\leq N\}$$
is *closed* in $H$. Indeed, a function $f$ is in $F_N$ if and only if $\vert Af(x)\vert\leq N$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, so $F_N$ is an intersection of closed sets.

Obviously, we have $H=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb N} F_N$. By the Baire category theorem, one of the closed sets $F_N$, say $F_{N_0}$, contains a nontrivial ball $B(f_0, r_0)$;  that is, we have $\Vert Af\Vert_\infty\leq N_0$ for all $f\in B(f_0,r_0)$. So your linear map $A$ is bounded on some ball, and hence it is continuous.